# php how download file from url and save it on server

Tags: php, csv, file-get-contents

my link (URL) is different!!! and does not work with usual method
I think because site load with js or aspx
you can test my link (URL) in your browser and see download starting
but cant work in php

I have tested all methods (fetch, curl, file, get, put), but it does not work.
I have a similar URL here: 'http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0'

I can open it in the browser and download a csv file I need to do this in php and save the csv file on server

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php

$file = fopen('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0');
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0');
file_put_contents('ClientTypeAll.csv', $file);

?>
```

I do not want Contents !!! I want a csv file form my link
if you test my link in your browser  download start in your pc

Comment: `$file_put_contents()`??? You meant `file_put_contents()`

Comment: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1) might be worth a read

Comment: "_you can test my link (URL) in your browser_" How, when "_my link (URL) is different!!!_"? That URL does nothing for me

Comment: 1-thanks brombeer , i forced use $  stackoverflow dont accept !

Comment: 'code' http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0 'code'
if test in your browser download start   but  in php  does not work
can you run this site in your location ? www.tsetmc.com

Comment: this site work with deep js and aspx ,  in browser load all part , but in php dont full load

Comment: As I said, that url does nothing for me. Takes too long. No error. I aborted after 15 seconds

Comment: maybe tset this site ' www.tsetmc.com'  its work for me very fast

Comment: Nope. Nothing. Since you misspelled `test` as `tset` in your previous comment I tried `www.testmc.com` - which brought up a (japanese?) site. Could that be the problem? A typo in your url?

Comment: @brombeer it's actually Korean, but all the same, OP's URL doesn't load for me either, and the testmc site doesn't prompt anything. OP you should start by opening up your browser's developer tools and studying what's actually happening. Chances are the CSV's URL will show up in your network tab.

Comment: tanks bro , no , my address is true , tse , tmc , its Tehran Securities Exchange Technology Management Co , in iran

Comment: i think goverment try to block other ip from iran and doesnot  load page for your ip ,  but tank you bro

Comment: _Tsetmc.com is DOWN for everyone.
It is not just you. The server is not responding..._ ... I'm guessing they may restrict international access?

Comment: its work fast for me and all ip from iran ,  my goverment try too make local internet simmilar china   and doesnot  upcomming for others ip ,,, you can run this site only with vpn vps  in iran ,

Answer (score 0):

I run this code with a remote PDF file.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://example.com/file.pdf';
$dir_name = 'storage-x'; // saVe the directory name

if (!file_exists($dir_name)) {
    mkdir($dir_name, 0777, true);
}
$path = $dir_name.'/'.rand().'.pdf';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($path, $file);

?>
```

Comment: thanks , does not work , maybe beacuse my server cannot load my address

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below step.

- Get file form URL.
- Set directory and check file exit condition and update directory access permission.
- Set new file path, name, and directory.
- Save the file.

Please check the below example which works for me.

```
<?php
     $file = file_get_contents('https://example.com/file.pdf');
     
     $dirName = 'storage-pdf';

     if (!file_exists($dirName)) {
         mkdir($dirName, 0777, true);
     }

     $newFilePath = $dirName.'/'.rand().'.pdf';
     
     file_put_contents($newFilePath, $file);
?>
```